# Google Adsense error -adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one AdSense head tag supported per page. The second tag is ignored

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I added my script tag to the navbar component. I get this error on my site when I next build with js:

```
Google Adsense error -adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one AdSense head tag supported per page. The second tag is ignored
```

```js
         <Head>
        <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-********" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        </Head>
```

Comment: Are you adding the AdSense script multiple times in your page? Could you provide additional code for the component where this is from?

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to call https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js in all adsense units. Need to use only once in header.
Means
Don't use "" this part in all units.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate